# How can I make a dynamic table without DataTable, but with the Table widget in FLUTTER?

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, row

I want to make a table with moving rows and columns inside, it also should be able to add a row or column with a button and delete it likewise. Internet only suggests Datatable or DataGrid, but I need to use the Table Widget in Flutter and Row and Column widgets if required. Can someone help me?